# IBAction in added xib subview does not work

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I have a MapKit app. I have replaced the callout view with a View from a .xib file. When the user taps on an annotation this subview appears with the following code:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didSelectAnnotationView annotation: MKAnnotationView!)
    {
        if let pin = annotation.annotation as? CustomPointAnnotation{

            if var infoView = UIView.viewFromNibName("myAnnView") as? myAnnView {
                infoView.nameLabel.text = pin.theTitle
                infoView.detailsLabel.text = pin.theDetails

                annotation.addSubview(infoView)

            } else {
                println("not the right type")
            }
        }
    }
```

The .xib file has two labels and a button. What I want to do is when the user presses this button it should "activate" a segue, but if I click on the button it does nothing. Here is the code for the View:

```
class MarkerInfoView: MKAnnotationView {


  @IBOutlet weak var placePhoto: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var detailsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var theButton: UIButton!

    private var hitOutside:Bool = true

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        let calloutViewAdded = self.superview != nil

        println("MapPin")

        if (selected || !selected && hitOutside) {
            super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        }

        self.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(self)

//        if (self == nil) {
//            self = MyAnnInfoView()
//        }

        if (self.selected && !calloutViewAdded) {
            addSubview(self)
        }

        if (!self.selected) {
            self.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

    override func hitTest(var point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        let viewPoint = superview?.convertPoint(point, toView: self) ?? point

        let isInsideView = pointInside(viewPoint, withEvent: event)

        var view = super.hitTest(viewPoint, withEvent: event)

        println("evrika")

        return view
    }

    override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        return CGRectContainsPoint(bounds, point)
    }

    @IBAction func readIt(sender: AnyObject) {
        println("evrika")
    } 
}
```

The "evrika" never appears. Why is this action not called and how can I  make it to be called?

Why I have a hard time doing this it is because I am not using the default Pins. Instead I am using this: https://github.com/RVLVR/REVClusterMap

and I have modified the REVClusterPin to this:

```
#import "REVClusterPin.h"

@implementation REVClusterPin
@synthesize title,coordinate,subtitle;
@synthesize nodes;
@synthesize selected;

- (NSUInteger) nodeCount
{
    if( nodes )
        return [nodes count];
    return 0;
}

- (UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    printf("hitTest");
    UIView* hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (hitView != nil)
    {
        [super bringSubviewToFront:self];
    }
    return hitView;
}

#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
- (void)dealloc
{
    [title release];
    [subtitle release];
    [nodes release];
    [super dealloc];
}
#endif

@end
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you connected your outlet  and action in xib?

Comment: Yes, of course I dit

Comment: In the [Creating Callouts section of the Location and Maps Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW28), it explains how to handle taps in custom callouts.  Look for the paragraph before Listing 6-7 that starts with "When you use a custom view instead of a standard callout...".

Comment: I have tried that, but still no results. What I didn't mentioned before is that I do not use the default Pins(for which I have found enough resources), instead I am using this https://github.com/RVLVR/REVClusterMap and I do not understand what I a doing wrong. Thank you Anna for helping me. I am the only developer here and I have absolutely no one to ask. P.S. I have changed it above code to give more details with what I have tried already